# how to move contents inside a bootstrap column to right or left?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, contact-form

I made a contact form where (col-md-6) for name,email and (col-md-6) for message text area.But I want to know how to make the input fields align to right and the message input field align left.Example...I want it to look like this.

```
                     (col-md-6)  (col-md-6)
                           Name  Message
                xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                          Email  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
              xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

                             <SUBMIT>
```

When i try to align text, only the text gets aligned to right..But not the input fields..Can someone help me.

```html
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-6">

    <div dir='rtl'>
      <label for="senderName">Name<span> * </span> 
      </label>
      <br>
      <input class="form-control" id="senderName" tabindex="1" type="text" name="senderName" required>
    </div>


    <label for="senderNumber">Phone<span> * </span> 
    </label>
    <br>
    <input class="form-control" id="senderNumber" tabindex="2" type="number" name="senderNumber" maxlength="15" minlength="10" required>




    <label for="senderEmail">Email<span> * </span>
    </label>
    <br>
    <input class="form-control" id="senderEmail" tabindex="3" type="email" name="senderEmail" required>


  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6">

    <label for="senderComments"><span class="special">Your Message</span>
    </label>
    <br>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="senderComments" tabindex="4" name="senderComments" rows="6"></textarea>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post your actual code

Comment: yes..I added my code

Answer (score 1):

You can use dir attribute:

```
<div dir='rtl'>   //rtl = right to left , dir = direction 

<span>name:</span>
<input type="text">
      .
      .
      .
      .
</div>
```

Comment: This is my current div for name
<label for="senderName">Name<span> * </span> </label><br>
<input class="form-control" id="senderName" tabindex="1" type="text" name="senderName" required>

But i wrapped like you said, it doesn't work...

Comment: can you edit your question above with adding the <from> code please ?

Comment: Ohh..sorry. It works..My css had a margin property that didn't let the input go to right...But after screen size reduces, how to make the that input field come to center...? Should i use css @media rule?

Comment: Looking at your code will make things easier for me.

Comment: you can use bootstrap grid system (col- *- *) instead of @media rule

Comment: oh sorry for late.  but you are asking deferent questions now,  and that shouldn't be here.  but you can read about grid system for better understanding.